# Passing a variable in Oracle APEX PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm building a simple application in APEX. One of my pages is a report and for the region source I have some code to this effect. The error message I'm receiving is

```
ORA-00904: "var_out": invalid identifier
```

Essentially the variable :form_variable is coming from a search box, and I can pass that into the query string fine (i.e. replacing "variable" with ":form_variable", but I want to pass it into a function first and put that output into the string instead. I'm sure this is something simple but for the life of me I can't work out what to do.

```
DECLARE
variable VARCHAR2(10);
query VARCHAR2(1000);

-- Where var_out is an output
BEGIN
myfunction(:form_variable, var_out);
variable := var_out;

query := 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column = variable';

RETURN query;

END;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your out variable, `var_out`, in your declaration block.

```
    DECLARE
    var_out VARCHAR2(10);
    query VARCHAR2(1000);

    -- Where var_out is an output
    BEGIN
    myfunction(:form_variable, var_out);
    --variable := var_out;

    query := 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column = '''||var_out||'''';

    RETURN query;

    END;
```

Also, your query string is not doing any replacement in your example. You could concatenate it if your procedure myfunction output cleans the variable.

Comment: It isn't necessary to declare 2 variables for the out parameter. Just passing variable or var_out would be sufficient. Also, when concatenating your variable to a query, remember that varchars need to be between quotes! -> column = '''||variable||''''; Just a heads up :)

Comment: @Tom Good catch on the concatenation, fixed that. And true, the extra variable is not needed.

Comment: Thanks that wasn't the full extent of my problem, but solved the trouble I was having with this bit of code. I found I only need 2 apostrophes surrounding the concatenation, not 3. The rest of my problem lied with APEX not liking me referring to a bind variable without using an if else statement to check if it had be set.